# Multidimensional dataSource fit to kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a multi dimensional datasource with a dynamic column like this:

```
{
TaskName: "Sample",
Oct12018: {
    Assigned: 2,
    Completed: 0
},
Oct22018: {
   Assigned: 2,
   Completed: 2
},
... and so on.
```

this is how I create that data:
I dynamically create a column for the date.

```
$.each(groupedData, function (col, val) {
                if (property != 'DateFormat' && property != 'Date') {
                    schedule[i] = {};
                    
                }
                for (var j = 0; j < val.length; j += 1) {
                    var currentItem = val[j]
                    var property = Object.keys(currentItem)[i];
                    schedule[i]["TaskDescription"] = currentItem.TaskDescription;
                    //schedule[i][currentItem.DateFormat] = currentItem["Assigned"];
                    for (var x = 0; x <= 2; x++) {
                        schedule[i][currentItem.DateFormat] = {};
                        schedule[i][currentItem.DateFormat]["Assigned"] = currentItem["Assigned"];
                        schedule[i][currentItem.DateFormat]["Completed"] = currentItem["Completed"];
                        //schedule[i]["Completed"] = currentItem["Completed"];
                    }
                }
                i += 1;
            });
```

Now I wonder how can I put this on my kendo grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, i was able to fit my grid with my dynamic column.

```
function generateColumns(sampleDataItem) {
        var columnNames = Object.keys(sampleDataItem[0]);
        return columnNames.map(function (name) {
                return {
                    field: name,
                    width: 200,
                    title: name,
        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Kendo-ui shows you [object][object], when you tried to parse a jsObject to string, that happens when you e.g call

```
JSON.stringify(data[i])            // data[i] = { actualData: "hi i am right", actualId: 0 }
```

instead of

```
JSON.stringify(data[i].actualData) // data[i].actualData = "hi i am right"
```

Try finding the parsing error and your grid should work again!

**Old answer:**

When you create your elements like you defined your kendo ui grid entrys, you can call

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.dataSource.add(yourElements);
```

Comment: can you elaborate more your answer?
I tried creating my own columns and bind it to my grid. still unable to show my Assigned and Completed value, it just shows [object] [object]

Comment: Ahh ok that's vital information, i will edit my answer!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the grid to treat the dynamic columns correctly you have to have them defined before the grid is instantiated. If you don't have the data beforehand, you can get around that by destroying the grid and then rebuilding it with the columns added to the columns property.